# Standard (netscape format) HTML Bookmarks Parser -> NSMutable Array of URLS and Names / Folders

Tags: objective-c

Could any stackoverflower kindly point me to a quick snippet, algorithm, code to achieve that?

Thaanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this isn't a complete implementation of what you want, the first thing that popped into my head was [Camino's bookmark importer](http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/camino/src/bookmarks/HTMLBookmarkConverter.m) (though it's changed to use NSXMLDocument instead of an NSScanner since I last dug into it).

(MPL license.)